# Reading image from XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I Read an `XML` file in `DataGridnView` But in `XML` file there are an images and in `Datagrindview` only read it as a path.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   DataSet A = new DataSet();
   A.ReadXml("C:/TrainedLabels.xml");
   dataGridView1.DataSource = A.Tables[0];
}
```

Here the `XML` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Faces_For_Training>
  <FACE>
    <NAME>john</NAME>
    <Age>25</Age>
    <informations>Student in MS uni</informations>
    <FILE>face_john 25Student in MSA university_905807542.jpg</FILE>
  </FACE>
  <FACE>
    <NAME>Alia</NAME>
    <Age>28</Age>
    <informations>engineer</informations>
    <FILE>face_Alia 28engineer_390671740.jpg</FILE>
  </FACE>
</Faces_For_Training>
```

it gives the path of Image like `face_Alia 28engineer_390671740.jpg` in `column` of `FILE`.
Any suggestions how I can read the images . Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Once the XML is read into your `DataSet` `A`, you can access the filename via `A.Tables[0].Columns["FILE"]`.  You can then use [`System.Drawing.Image.FromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to load it.

Comment: Thank you thought for Response , I think using xml as a database is a bad idea for me hehe . so I will database by vs and make it for my face Recognition . Thank you very much again :) .